# Why is my website a blank screen in IE? (Including IE9!)

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer, google-custom-search

Launched my website – http://www.artsbrand.co.uk – yesterday without having tested the finished product on IE. Now that I have, it initially brings up completely unstyled html, then after a couple of seconds the screen just goes blank. When that happens, this is the only thing in the source:

`<script defer onreadystatechange='google.loader.domReady()' src=//:></script>`

Does this have something to do with my Google Custom Search Engine?

I have a few conditional comments, which I'll list below in case they're important:

1. First I set up the html class (the no-js class is for Modernizr):

   ```
   <!--[if lt IE 7 ]><!--> <html class="ie ie6 no-js" dir="ltr" lang="en-GB" xmlns:og="http://opengraphprotocol.org/schema/"> <!--<![endif]-->
   <!--[if IE 7 ]><!-->    <html class="ie ie7 no-js" dir="ltr" lang="en-GB" xmlns:og="http://opengraphprotocol.org/schema/"> <!--<![endif]-->
   <!--[if IE 8 ]><!-->    <html class="ie ie8 no-js" dir="ltr" lang="en-GB" xmlns:og="http://opengraphprotocol.org/schema/"> <!--<![endif]-->
   <!--[if IE 9 ]><!-->    <html class="ie ie9 no-js" dir="ltr" lang="en-GB" xmlns:og="http://opengraphprotocol.org/schema/"> <!--<![endif]-->
   <!--[if gt IE 9]><!--><html class="no-js" dir="ltr" lang="en-GB" xmlns:og="http://opengraphprotocol.org/schema/"><!--<![endif]-->
   ```
2. Then I set up three different stylesheets with media queries:

   ```
   <!--[if !IE]><!-->
   <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen and (max-width: 489px)" href="<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_directory'); ?>/device.css" />
   <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen and (min-width: 490px) and (max-width: 899px)" href="<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_directory'); ?>/smallscreen.css" />
   <!--<![endif]-->
   <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen and (min-width: 900px)" href="<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_directory'); ?>/style.css" />
   ```
3. This one's just for Sticky Footer (as per the instructions here http://www.cssstickyfooter.com/style.css ):

   ```
   <!--[if !IE 7]><!-->
   <style type="text/css">
     #wrap {display:table;height:100%}
   </style>
   <!--<![endif]-->
   ```

I only have access to IE7 and IE9, but the behaviour is exactly the same in both of those – 1-2 seconds of unstyled page (I saw a split second of CSS once in IE9!) followed by sheer blankness. I'd be very grateful for any help you guys can offer!

**EDIT -** I'm less convinced it has anything to do with conditional comments now – I just tried getting rid of all of them and it made no difference at all. I should probably also mention that I've tried both versions of Google CSE (Search Element V1 and Search Element V2) and the results were the same.

**UPDATE -** I've got a fairly messy workaround now, although the search will have to be out of action in IE for now. The problem was a combination of my dodgy use of media queries/conditional comments (I'm new to both of them!) and the **still unknown** issue that's causing IE to react badly with the Google CSE. So anyway here's what my stylesheet links look like now:

```
<!--[if !IE]><!-->
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen and (max-width: 489px)" href="<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_directory'); ?>/device.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen and (min-width: 490px) and (max-width: 899px)" href="<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_directory'); ?>/smallscreen.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen and (min-width: 900px)" href="<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_directory'); ?>/style.css" />
<!--<![endif]-->

<!--[if IE]>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_directory'); ?>/style.css" />
<![endif]-->
```

Meanwhile the search script is wrapped in [if !IE] comments.

Comment: It displays in my IE9 just as it does in Firefox, and the html displays in IE7/8 (using dev tools), although it looks like your css includes are somehow borked. (Edit: Compatibility Mode displays just as IE7/8.)

Comment: Yup the html is showing now, but only because I've now surrounded the Google CSE script with conditional comments. Not a permanent solution, unfortunately. Any idea what's up with the CSS?

Comment: Ah no my bad I just forgot to take the 'min-width' media query out when calling the IE-only stylesheet.

Answer (score 1):

This is just a guess because I can't get my IE7 machine to boot right now, but I think it may be because the script you have is before the closing `head` tag.

From what I remember, IE does weird things when you try to access elements on the page that haven't been fully parsed yet.

`var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(gcse, s);` is essentially trying to insert the new `script` tag before the very first `script` tag, which is inside the uncompleted head tag.

I thought `s.parentNode` would be `null` (or `undefined`) in this case, but apparently it's something else, maybe the whole document?  Who knows, IE does crazy things.

At any rate, what I'd try is moving that google script tag inside the `body` of your page, instead of in the `head`, and see if that makes a difference.

As for the CSS, IE before 9 doesn't support [media queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/Media_queries).  You can use something like [respondjs](https://github.com/scottjehl/Respond) to make it work in IE, but you need to put the queries in the CSS file, not in the `link` tag itself.